# RDS to S3 - Data Transformation AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, data-transfer

I have about 30 tables in my RDS postgres / oracle (haven't decided if it is oracle or postgres yet) instance. I want to fetch all the records that have been inserted / updated in the last 4 hours (configurable) , create a csv file pertaining to each table and store the files in S3. I want this whole process to be transactional. If there is any error in fetching data from one table , I don't want data pertinent to other 29 tables to be persisted in S3. The data isn't very large , it should be in the order of few 100 records or less in each table for the duration of 4 hours.

I am thinking of having a spark job in EMR cluster to fetch data from RDS , create a csv for each table and post all the files to S3 at the end of the process. The EMR cluster will be destroyed once data is posted to S3.  A cloudwatch trigger will invoke a lamda every 4 hours which will spin up a new EMR cluster which performs this job.

Are there any alternate approaches worth exploring for this transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/) which is using EMR under the hood but you don't need to care about infrastructure and configurations, just [setup crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) and [write your ETL job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-scala.html).

Please note that AWS Glue doesn't support predicates pushdown for JDBC connections ([currently s3 only](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/)) so it means it will load entire table first and only then apply filtering.

Also you should carefully think about atomicity since Glue ETL job simply processes data and writes to a sink without transactions. In case of failure it won't remove partially written records so you should manage it by yourself. There are few options I would consider:

1. Write data into temp folder (local or s3) per each execution and then move objects to final destination with [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command or copy data using [TransferManager from AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html)
2. Write data to the final destination into dedicated folder and in case of failure delete it using CLI or SDK

Comment: Thanks @Yuriy. I'll try this out.